# Analyzing a recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to figure out this algorithm that accepts an input of an `int` and should return an output of the sum of each element in the `int`.

```
# Input -> 4321
# output -> 10 (4+3+2+1) 

def sum_func(n):

    # Base case
    if len(str(n)) == 1:
        return n

    # Recursion
    else:
        return n%10 + sum_func(n/10)
```

When Trying to break apart this algorithm this is what I come up with

```
1st loop -> 1 + 432 = 433
2nd loop -> 2 + 43 = 45
3rd loop -> 3 + 4 = 7
4th loop -> 4 + 4 = 8
```

How was it able to come up with the result of `10`?

Comment: 1) there is no loop in the code; 2) the first expression should be 1 + sum_func(432) where the second term gives a result of 9 if you dig into it.

Comment: (for all positive `n`) `len(str(n)) == 1` is an odd way of writing `n < 10`

Comment: Looks like you're using Python. Be sure to compare `n/10` vs `n//10`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unwinding, it would look like this:

```
sum_func(4321)
= 1 + sum_func(432)
= 1 + 2 + sum_func(43)
= 1 + 2 + 3 + sum_func(4)
= 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
```

Answer (score 3):

When trying to understand recursion you'll have to clearly understand what is returned.

In this case function `sum_func(n)` returns the **sum of the digits** in it's argument `n`.

For concrete `n` task is divided into `last_digit_of_n` + `sum_func(n_without_last_digit)`.

For example,

`sum_func(4321) = 
sum_func(432) + 1 = 
sum_func(43) + 2 + 1 = 
sum_func(4) + 3 + 2 + 1 = 
4 + 3 + 2 + 1`

Hope this helps.

(As a side note, checking if n has more than one digit using `str` is a bad idea. Better just to check if `n <= 9`)

Comment: This drove me crazy and you explained it in a very simple way thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must reach the base case before the summation occurs:

```
Iteration 1: 1 + sum_func(432)
Iteration 2: 1 + 2 + sum_func(43)
Iteration 3: 1 + 2 + 3 + sum_func(4) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10
```